# How to use audio from discord so recognize_google can understand

Tags: python, discord.py, speech-recognition, pycord

I am trying to take audio said in a discord Voice chat and put it inside the recognize_google function to find what is said in the VC. I am doing it by using the pycord libary for record and stop_recording and once_done is a callback function for stop_recording.

This is my code- as you can see I go through every file and I make an AudioData object using file.fp.read(). I don't get any error when I run the code it is just that the recognize_google funtion does not understand the words I am saying. Thank you in advance for any help :)

```
import discord
import speech_recognition as sr

async def once_done(sink: discord.sinks, channel: discord.TextChannel, *args):
    
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    await sink.vc.disconnect()  # Disconnect from the voice channel.
    files = [discord.File(audio.file, f"{user_id}.{sink.encoding}") for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()]  # List down the files.
    
    for file in files:
        try:
            audio_data = sr.AudioData(file.fp.read(), 48000, 2)
    
            text = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio_data).lower()
```

Comment: `discord` and  `sr` are not defined.  please define these. the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok I added them